# Consuming REST resources before rendering in React.js

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I have React components that consumes external webservice to reach data for rendering.
I would like the data being loaded BEFORE the rendering because I want it to be indexed by search engines.

Here is my component :

```
class AboutPage extends React.Component {

    async componentWillMount() {
        let response = await EventWS.doSearch();

        this.setState({
            eventList : response.data
        })
    }

    render() {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

(I tried to use async/await because I thought it could help, but no).

When trying to load the page with server side rendering I got the warning :

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounting component. This usually means you called setState() outside componentWillMount() on the server. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the FluxContainer(AboutPage) component.
```

Indicating that the setState is done AFTER the componentWillMount has ended.

In my specific case, what is best way to acheving this ? Is there a easy way to do an ajax call synchronously ? Is it recommended to do so ?

Thank you.

EDIT :
I have found a library that allow to make synchronous call :
https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request

But it states that it is not well suited for production. So I'am a bit disapointed.

Comment: This ticket is discussing async componentWillMount https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1739 . Maybe you can find som pointers there

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a lot of experience with Flux but it seems like you should do this in the componentDidMount method.

Comment: I think componentDidMount is always executed on the client side. ComponentWillMount is executed on the server side, so it is the one that must be used for server-side rendering.

Comment: Without a mounted component you cannot set the state so you will have to find another way to pass the data to your component. Maybe a container component that passes a function prop for you to call when the async completes?

Comment: The problem is not that the component is mounting. The problem is that the ajax call is resolved after the componentWillMount function has ended.
If I use a container, I will have the same problem : how to load response before rendering the container ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) promise based [get](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#axiosgeturl-config) in `componentDidMount` to implement it, for an example you can refer [Handling Events In React](https://aggarwalarpit.wordpress.com/2017/05/15/handling-events-in-react/) and below sample code:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {eventList: []};
   this.Axios = axios.create();
}

componentDidMount() {
        let _this = this;
        this.Axios.get('/your/rest/url')
           .then(function (response) {
               console.log(response);
               _this.setState({eventList: response.data});
           }).catch(function (error) {
               console.log(error);
           });
}
```

Or if you are already using `Axios` then make sure `EventWS.doSearch()` return [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to you and call it in `componentDidMount`, as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {eventList: []};
}

componentDidMount() {
        let _this = this;
        EventWS.doSearch().then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            _this.setState({eventList: response.data});
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I think you misread the question. In fact I already use Axios, even it is hidden by EventWS class.

Comment: then make sure `EventWS.doSearch();` return promise for you and call it in 
`componentDidMount`

Comment: This is not the question.